# Build Error solution in wrong location

Tags: c#

I am trying to run my program but am currently getting a build error and don't know how to resolve it.

This is the error I am getting:

> Compile complete -- 1 errors, 0 warnings
>   Build started 03/04/2014 10:24:48.
>   ResolveAssemblyReferences:
>     A TargetFramework profile exclusion list will be generated.
>   CoreResGen:
>     No resources are out of date with respect to their source files. Skipping resource generation.
>   GenerateTargetFrameworkMonikerAttribute:
>   Skipping target "GenerateTargetFrameworkMonikerAttribute" because all output files are up-to-date with respect to the input files.
>   CoreCompile:
>     C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\Csc.exe /noconfig /nowarn:1701,1702 /nostdlib+ /platform:x86 /errorreport:prompt /warn:4 /define:DEBUG;TRACE /errorendlocation /preferreduilang:en-US /highentropyva- /reference:"C:\Program Files\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework.NETFramework\v4.0\Profile\Client\Microsoft.CSharp.dll" /reference:"C:\Program Files\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework.NETFramework\v4.0\Profile\Client\mscorlib.dll" /reference:"C:\Program Files\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework.NETFramework\v4.0\Profile\Client\System.Core.dll" /reference:"C:\Program Files\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework.NETFramework\v4.0\Profile\Client\System.Data.DataSetExtensions.dll" /reference:"C:\Program Files\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework.NETFramework\v4.0\Profile\Client\System.Data.dll" /reference:"C:\Program Files\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework.NETFramework\v4.0\Profile\Client\System.Deployment.dll" /reference:"C:\Program Files\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework.NETFramework\v4.0\Profile\Client\System.dll" /reference:"C:\Program Files\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework.NETFramework\v4.0\Profile\Client\System.Drawing.dll" /reference:"C:\Program Files\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework.NETFramework\v4.0\Profile\Client\System.Windows.Forms.dll" /reference:"C:\Program Files\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework.NETFramework\v4.0\Profile\Client\System.Xml.dll" /reference:"C:\Program Files\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework.NETFramework\v4.0\Profile\Client\System.Xml.Linq.dll" /debug+ /debug:full /filealign:512 /optimize- /out:"obj\x86\Debug\Jitters Coffee Application.exe" /resource:obj\x86\Debug\Jitters_Coffee_Application.frmLogin.resources /resource:obj\x86\Debug\Jitters_Coffee_Application.frmJittersCoffee.resources /resource:obj\x86\Debug\Jitters_Coffee_Application.Properties.Resources.resources /target:winexe /utf8output Form1.cs Form1.Designer.cs JittersCoffee.cs JittersCoffee.Designer.cs LoginDetails.cs OrderData.cs Properties\AssemblyInfo.cs Properties\Resources.Designer.cs Properties\Settings.Designer.cs "C:\Users\ac240087l\AppData\Local\Temp.NETFramework,Version=v4.0,Profile=Client.AssemblyAttributes.cs"
>
> Build FAILED.
>
> Time Elapsed 00:00:01.69

The program I am trying to run was working at home on my laptop but won't run at college. As far as I can tell it is looking for program in wrong location (I drive) but it is in the E drive now.

Comment: I would expect the error to be _above_ the "Compile complete" line, so before the part that you posted.

Comment: Usually the paths to projects in the solution file are relative. Also, if a project is not found, it will be listed as unavailable in the solution explorer. The IDE will not try to build it. So I'd suspect that the reason is a missing file in a project or something else. Unfortunately, your log does not tell anything on why the build failed. Maybe you can post some more (especially above the line "Compile complete").

Comment: This is the line above compile complete:

Comment: ------ Build started: Project: Jitters Coffee Application, Configuration: Release x86 ------
error CS5001: Program 'E:\Software Development\Term 3\Developing Apps\Project - Jitters Coffee\Jitters Coffee Application\Jitters Coffee Application\obj\x86\Release\Jitters Coffee Application.exe' does not contain a static 'Main' method suitable for an entry point

Answer (score 0):

Your project misses the `Main` method that was defined as its entry point.

- If it is a console application, it might be that the file that contains the method was missing.
- If it is another type of application, it might be a misconfiguration in the project settings. Check the startup object in the properties of the project and assert that this value is valid.